# MySQL join "connected" intervals

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have table

```
teach_subject(teacher_id, subject_id, min_grade_of_school, max_grade_of_school, color_in_timetable)
```

Example data:

```
teacher_id  subject_id  min_grade_of_school  max_grade_of_school  color_in_timetable
         1           2                    1                    4               #A00
         1           2                    5                    6               #0A0
         1           2                    9                   11               #00A
         1           3                    1                    7               #AA0
```

It is not allowed that `min_grad_of_school > max_grad_of_school`, but maybe they are equal.
It is also not allowed that for a given tuple `(t_id_new, s_id_new, min_grade_new, max_grade_new, color_new)` there exists an other tuple `(t_id, s_id, min_grade, max_grade, color)` in the table holding
`t_id_new = t_id` and `s_id_new = s_id` and
`( min_grade <= min_grade_new <= max_grade` or `min_grade <= max_grade_new <= max_grade )`

So for the given example a new tuple like `(1,2,6,11,#FFF)` or `(1,2,2,7,#FFF)` is not possible.

So far no problem.

Now I want to ignore the color and join the "connected" rows, i.e. if teacher 1 teaches subject 2 from the 1st grade to the 4th grade, and from the 5th grade to the 6th grade, you can also say he teaches subject 2 from 1st to 6th grade.
So I want to "join" the tuples `(1,2,1,4)` and `(1,2,5,6)` to `(1,2,1,6)` but i dont want to join (1,2,4,5) and (1,2,9,11), since ther is a (integer) gap between 5 and 9.

I just have no idea if there is a way to do this with MySQL.  At the moment I just select all the data an edit the selected data  with PHP. Is there a MySQL way to directly select what I want or should stick to PHP?

**Edit**

Example result (for the above example data) :

```
teacher_id  subject_id  min_grade_of_school  max_grade_of_school  color_in_timetable
         1           2                    1                    6               #A00
         1           2                    9                   11               #00A
         1           3                    1                    7               #AA0
```

**Edit 2**

Maybe can use a stored procedure?

Comment: What do you mean JOIN the tuples?Put in expected results.

Comment: I did so. I want to "join"  `(a, b, c, d) ` and `(a, b, c2,d2)` if `d+1=c2`. the result should be `(a, b, c, d2)`.

Comment: Do you have a primary key?

Comment: I have added a column named `id` which is an autoincrement. but the tuple `(teacher_id, subject_id, min_grade_of_school, max_grade_of_school)` is also  set as a unique key

Comment: What should the desired result look like?

Comment: I added a example result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS teach_subject;

CREATE TABLE teach_subject
(teacher_id INT NOT NULL
,subject_id INT NOT NULL
,min_g INT NOT NULL
,max_g INT NOT NULL
,color_in_timetable CHAR(4) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(teacher_id,subject_id,min_g)
);

INSERT INTO teach_subject VALUES
(1,2,1,4,'#A00'),
(1,2,5,6,'#0A0'),
(1,2,9,11,'#00A'),
(1,3,1, 7,'#AA0');

SELECT a.teacher_id
     , a.subject_id
     , a.min_g
     , MIN(c.max_g) max_g
     , a.color_in_timetable
  FROM teach_subject a
  LEFT 
  JOIN teach_subject b 
    ON b.teacher_id = a.teacher_id
   AND b.subject_id = a.subject_id
   AND b.min_g = a.max_g - 1
  LEFT 
  JOIN teach_subject c 
    ON c.teacher_id = a.teacher_id
   AND c.subject_id = a.subject_id
   AND c.min_g >= a.min_g 
  LEFT 
  JOIN teach_subject d 
    ON d.teacher_id = a.teacher_id
   AND d.subject_id = a.subject_id
   AND d.min_g = c.max_g + 1
 WHERE b.teacher_id IS NULL 
   AND c.teacher_id IS NOT NULL
   AND d.teacher_id IS NULL
 GROUP 
    BY a.teacher_id,a.subject_id,a.min_g; 

+------------+------------+-------+-------+--------------------+
| teacher_id | subject_id | min_g | max_g | color_in_timetable |
+------------+------------+-------+-------+--------------------+
|          1 |          2 |     1 |     6 | #A00               |
|          1 |          2 |     9 |    11 | #00A               |
|          1 |          3 |     1 |     7 | #AA0               |
+------------+------------+-------+-------+--------------------+
```

Comment: I thought about something like this, but it could be that there are up to 13 tuple with the same `teacher_id` and `subject_id` and `min_grade_of_school = max_grade_of_school`.  this join then will get very big... and maybe also very slow?

Comment: ? It won't get any *bigger* than it is now. On a larger data set, it may get slow.

Comment: ah sorry, I haven't read it right (I'm not on a pc, right now, so I can not test it and see what happens). I was afraid of having a big join over 13 tables :-D. but now I see the point. since the join uses a unique key it should get too slow. thanks I will test this as soon as I'm back at an pc.

Comment: So I have tested it. It works fine but there is al little error in the code that shows if you add the row `(1,2,7,7,#123)`. It has to be `b.max_g = a.min_g - 1` instead of `b.min_g = a.max_g - 1`

Comment: sadly this type of query does not fit into a view using the merge algorithm since it uses `group by` and `min`. do you have a tip for this too? maybe i just not use a view here and just use "normal" querys.

Comment: 1. I'm not saying that there isn't an error, but I'm not sure that your fix is quite right (I might be wrong though). 2. What's wrong with a view?

Comment: 1. Table `b` is used to mark a row in table `a` as the start of an interval, so there should be no entry with `b.max+1 = a.min`, so the row of table `a` starts an interval.  

2. If I use a view, the temptable algorithm will be used. so I get a table with the data I want, but i lost all the keys I set. so If I use a Join with this view, mysql has to make a full table scan on the view to find what i'm looking for. Or did i understand this wrong?

Comment: 1. Hm. 2. OK, but that's a limitation of views, not this query !?!?!?

Comment: Yes, but sometimes you one can write it a little bit different and make the query work with the merge algorithm of a view. but I dont think this is possible or would be nice in this case^^